# iPhone Implement a list of customized styled text in a scrollview

Tags: iphone, fonts, scroll

I need a small FAQ page with Question in bold font and answer in normal. And the list if long enough to span out of iPhone Length so it should be scrollable. I considered implementing a UITextView which gives me scroll functionality automatically. However it does not allow me to custom style the text (i.e. style different lines differently). Any suggestion how this can be achieved? I am using xcode 3.1.3 and IB - 3.1.2 and iPhone SDK 3.0.
Any help highly appreciated ... I am banging my head on this thing for more than a day now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked - [iPhone SDK: How can I add a scroll view to my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040519/iphone-sdk-how-can-i-add-a-scroll-view-to-my-application)